# É seguro criar ponteiro para objeto no stack indiretamente?

Tags: c++, stack

A minha classe possui um método que retorna um ponteiro pra si mesma, e em algum momento eu uso o seguinte :

```
void classequalquer::metodo() {
    ClasseA * ponteiro = ClasseA().getThis();
    //usa o ponteiro nesse método sem usar delete
}

//Para referências
ClasseA* ClasseA::getThis() {
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Rodrigo, pra você ter uma resposta mais precisa, forneça um exemplo de código do que `ClasseA().getThis()` devolve, pois como já foi bem explicado na resposta que você teve, a "segurança" disso vai depender de como o ponteiro alocado está sendo manipulado além desse trecho de código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**O trecho postado não é seguro:**

```
void classequalquer::metodo() {
  ClasseA * ponteiro = ClasseA().getThis();
  //deferenciar o ponteiro aqui é comportamento indefinido
  //o objeto não existe mais
}
```

`ponteiro` pega o endereço de um objeto criado como temporário para a operação de atribuição. O objeto não está disponível ao fim do ponto sequencial que encerra a operação, e `ponteiro` referencia endereço invalidado. **É ilegal pegar o endereço de um `rvalue`.**

---

**Retornar o ponteiro através de um método é seguro:**

Apesar do trecho postado, retornar o ponteiro através de um método é seguro, e o trecho deveria ser adaptado para a seguinte forma:

```
void classequalquer::metodo() {
  ClasseA A;
  ClasseA * ponteiro = A.getThis();
  //usa o ponteiro nesse método sem usar delete
  //o objeto ainda existe
}
```

Mas o método é desnecessário (e eu pessoalmente o desencorajo), qualquer escopo de código que tenha acesso a `ClasseA::getThis()` tem também acesso ao operador `&`, que tem função de retornar endereço:

```
void classequalquer::metodo() {
  ClasseA A;
  ClasseA * ponteiro = &A;
}
```

**Algo semelhante, retornar uma referência a si, é bem comum:**

Algo muito semelhante a retornar um ponteiro para si é bastante usado, como no `overload` de operadores de atribuição, onde retorna-se uma referência ao próprio objeto (criada através da desreferenciação do `this`), por exemplo:

```
ClasseA& ClasseA::operator = (ClasseA const & outra) {
  //..(algumas operações de atribuição)..
  return *this; //semelhante a retornar ponteiro, (refere-se a este objeto)
                //mas a referência é mais transparente.
                //assim como o ponteiro, 
                //  a referência será invalidada quando o objeto for destruído
}
```

Comment: eu ia responder esta pergunta, mas não o fiz porque não consegui produzir um erro no Visual Studio 2005 com um teste simples...
mas o objetivo do comentário é dizer que a declaração "ClasseA A()" acima não declara uma instância de Classe A, e sim uma função chamada A que retorna uma instância de ClasseA...é uma situação conhecida como "the most vexing parse" no C++

Comment: @JoséX. Então minha resposta está errada! Importa-se de elaborar uma resposta? Eu voto na sua e deleto a minha. Ou edito aqui onde comento o trecho dele?

Comment: calma, meu amigo...concordo totalmente com você que utilizar um ponteiro para um objeto temporário causa comportamento indefinido...a observação sobre "the most vexing parse" foi uma observação adicional, que não tem relação com a pergunta feita pelo OP

Comment: @JoséX. Corrigi a declaração. Está correto agora, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo mostrando o comportamento indefinido ao se utilizar o recurso usado pelo OP.

```
// arquivo ptrtest.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
      int x;
      A();
      A* getThis() { return this; }
};

A::A()
{
   cout << "* this=" << (void*)this << '\n';
   x = 42;
   cout << "* &A::x=" << (void*)&x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   A* aPtr;
   aPtr = A().getThis();
   int z = 1;
   cout << "* &aPtr= " << (void*)&aPtr << '\n';
   cout << "* &z=    " << (void*)&z << '\n';
   cout << "* A::x=  " << aPtr->x << '\n';
}
```

Compilando o código acima no gcc 6.3.1 com a linha de comando

```
g++ -O3 -o ptrtest ptrtest.cpp
```

(Opção -O3 otimiza o código gerado).

Ao executar, o resultado é:

```
* this=0x7ffdd82e7550
* &A::x=0x7ffdd82e7550
* &aPtr= 0x7ffdd82e7558
* &z=    0x7ffdd82e7550
* A::x=  1
```

Notar que a variável A::x foi sobrescrita pelo valor de z.

Compilando sem otimização:

```
g++ -o ptrtest ptrtest.cpp
```

Ao executar, o resultado agora é:

```
* this=0x7ffdd82e7550
* &A::x=0x7ffdd82e7550
* &aPtr= 0x7ffdd82e7558
* &z=    0x7ffdd82e7550
* A::x=  42
```

Notar que a variável A::x agora **não** foi sobrescrita pelo valor de z.

Isso demonstra que utilizar endereços de valores temporários possui **comportamento indefinido**. Neste caso, dependendo das opções de compilação o programa apresenta comportamentos diferentes. Os efeitos poderiam ser mais drásticos, como o programa apresentar exceção de endereçamento, ou ficar em loop, etc, **qualquer** comportamento poderia acontecer (de acordo com a definição da linguagem), porque esta é a definição de comportamento indefinidio: em princípio, qualquer coisa pode acontecer.

Answer (score 1):

Depende o que faz com o ponteiro.

O objeto está sendo criado no *stack*, isto você já sabe. Portanto o ponteiro referenciará uma posição no *stack*. Quando esta função acabar, o objeto deixa de existir, não pode mais haver uma referência para ele. Mas a referência criada aí também se vai, então ok. Mas e se você escapou a referência para algum objeto, jogando o ponteiro nele e esse objeto sobrevive mais que esta função? Você estará acessando um objeto que não existe mais. E não sei o que é pior, dar um erro, ou parecer que funciona em vários cenários, mas não em todos.

Não teria porque usar o `delete` se não usou um `new`.

Agora se por acaso o `getThis()` retornar um outro objeto criado no *heap*, aí tem que gerenciar isto, mas não parece ser o caso.

Comment: getThis literalmente é 'return this'

Comment: Os cuidados referentes a ponteiros soltos são válidos, mas acho que você deixou escapar que o objeto (no código postado) não dura até o fim da função, mas é destruído ao fim da expressão.

Comment: @Kahler é verdade, isso que dá responder de madrugada. Quando respondi não tinha toda informação disponível.

Comment: E eu me enganei no código da minha resposta. O José X. me corrigiu.

Comment: @Kahler penso o mesmo que ele, não considero sua resposta errada, só não foi no ponto exato. Agora acho que ficou perfeita.